# mySQL JOIN from different TABLE different RECORD

Tags: mysql, sql, select, left-join

I'm trying to join two tables, but inputs are not the same.

On table **Category** `category_id` is an integer.

But on table **url_alias** `category` is a string like `category_id=15`.

I've tried:

```
SELECT * FROM category c
LEFT JOIN url_alias ua ON ( ua.category = 'category_id=c.category_id')
```

No luck. How can I reach that table?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have placed `c.catagory_id` inside the quotes (`'`), thus making it part of the string literal. Instead, you should `concat` its value to `category_id=` literal:

```
SELECT    * 
FROM      category c
LEFT JOIN url_alias ua ON ua.category = CONCAT('category_id=', c.category_id)
```